# How can i do so i dont crash my program, when i enter a character instead of a int

Tags: c#, while-loop, tryparse

and this is one of my first "almost working programs", the thing is that when i type a character instead of a int, my application instantly crashes. And i know that i have to do something with tryparse or something like that, im just not currently sure how i should put it in my code, since its a loop.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace threeTries
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Yellow;
            Console.Title = "3 Tries";
            Console.WriteLine("3 Tries\n-------");
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;

            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000);
            Console.Clear();
            Console.WriteLine("You have to score the highest score possible\nYou have to answer simple math questions\n  ");
            Console.Clear();

            var score = 0;
            var tries = 0;
            bool highscore = false;
            var numberHighscore = 0;

            while (true)
            {
                Random rngNumber = new Random();
                var num1 = rngNumber.Next(1, 100);
                var num2 = rngNumber.Next(1, 100);
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Yellow;
                if (highscore == true)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Your highscore is {0}", numberHighscore);
                }
                Console.WriteLine("{0} Score  ||  Tries {1}/3", score, tries);
                Console.ResetColor();
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;

                Console.WriteLine("What is {0} + {1} ?", num1, num2);
                Console.Write("Answer : ");
                int answer = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

                if (answer == num1 + num2)
                {
                    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
                    Console.WriteLine("Your answer was correct");
                    score++;
                    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
                    Console.Clear();
                }
                if (answer != num1 + num2)
                {
                    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
                    Console.WriteLine("Your answer is wrong");
                    tries++;
                    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
                    Console.Clear();
                }
                if (tries > 3) {
                    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
                    Console.WriteLine("Game Over");
                    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
                    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Yellow;
                    Console.WriteLine("Your final score was {0}", score);
                    numberHighscore = score;
                    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);
                    highscore = true;
                    score = 0;
                    tries = 0;
                    Console.Clear();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If its user input causing the issue, add validation on the input screen to force an int before it even gets to this code.

Comment: `int answer = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());` <---that's where your problem is.  do some checks on the value before converting to int to make sure it's in fact a number, else prompt the user and let them know that they've entered in garbage data.  Also for your own sanity, you may wanna clean up the blank lines between the curly braces at the bottom of the code....personally this would drive me nuts.

Comment: You also could replace `if(answer != num1 + num2)` with `else` (not the problem but still worth understanding)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest way is something like

```
int answer;
while (!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out answer))
{
    Console.Write("You didn't provide a number, please try again:");
}
```

Comment: This worked. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Edit: Evertude's solution is much more succinct.

You could use a try catch and try converting the input to an integer.

```
int answer = 0;
while(answer == 0)
{
    try
    {
        var inputAnswer = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        answer = inputAnswer;
    }catch
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter a valid number.");
    }
}
```

Comment: This works also

Comment: Though it's probably not a huge deal with this sort of simple application, it should be noted that going this route is potentially a significant performance hit.  It's always better to validate for stuff like this as opposed to having it fall through to a `catch` statement if you can avoid it.